# ¿Cómo puedo dar estilo a un párrafo de texto ingresado desde un modal?

Tags: php, mysql, css, html5

Cuando ingreso un párrafo de texto con saltos de línea desde un modal, al insertarlo a la bd y mostrarlo en el frontend me muestra el párrafo sin dichos saltos de línea.

Comment: En un modal ???? por casualidad no querrás decir textarea??

Comment: Si, dentro del modal se encuentran el textarea

Comment: Prueba reemplazar los `\n` por `<br>`

Comment: Muestra el código del modal como lo tienes porfa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ello debes utilizar `nl2br($texto);` de esa forma te mostrara los saltos de linea que tienes en la base de datos

Comment: Saludos @chocokrizpis, podrías mejorar tu respuesta agregando enlaces de documentación y tal vez copiando un poco de información que esta misma tiene. Así la información que tiene tu respuesta será más comprensible y tendrá mayor aceptación por la comunidad. ;)

Comment: Gracias, me ha solucionado mi problema!